# How to identify dissimilar subsets of binary variables in R?

Tags: r

Thanks for reading my post. I have a binary matrix `(0,1)` where the variables are in columns and instances in rows. I am trying to calculate a score for the instances(row) by summing up the elements in each row. However, I would like, for each row independently, to apply a dissimilarity subsetting where I only sum non-redundant variables. For a couple of variables X and Y, the similarity I am using is

```
sim= |intersect(X,Y)| / | unity(X,Y)|
```

For example, if `row (i)` has 6 positive values (from 6 different variables), but 2 pairs are higher than 0.8 similarity, the corrected score will be 4 instead of 6 where one variable from each redundant pair is removed.

I understand that I can do a universal data reduction in order to remove the highly correlated variables, but in my case, I prefer to keep them all due to data sparsity and then applying a similarity correction for each row. Having the squared similarity matrix already calculated, how can I loop over rows to correct the summation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you can do it like this.

First, I'll create a reproducible example. We'll make a matrix of 5 columns and 10 rows:

```r
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rbinom(5*10, 1, .5), nrow=10)
m
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#>  [1,]    1    0    1    1    0
#>  [2,]    1    1    0    1    0
#>  [3,]    0    1    1    0    0
#>  [4,]    1    0    1    1    1
#>  [5,]    1    0    0    0    0
#>  [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
#>  [7,]    1    1    0    0    1
#>  [8,]    0    0    1    0    1
#>  [9,]    1    0    0    1    1
#> [10,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

You said you already have a similarity metric matrix, here I'll just use correlation for demonstration purposes:

```r
sim <- cor(m)
diag(sim) <- 0
```

You have some threshold of similarity, above which you want to exclude observations from the sum. Since similarity is measured at the column level which columns you want to exclude will be the same for all rows -- we just need to figure out which columns we want to drop. We can do this by checking which observations are larger then the threshold (here I use .5) and then collapsing the matrix of similarity to a vector by summing along columns.

```r
sim <- sim>.5

cols_to_keep <- as.numeric(colSums(sim)==0)
cols_to_keep
#> [1] 0 1 1 0 1
```

We now have a vector that is 0 for columns that are too similar, and 1 for 'unique' columns. Since the rows you are summing are binary vectors, the sum of each row while omitting rows that are similar is simply the inner product of each matrix row and the binary vector of column similarity. This makes the computation fast and easy:

```r
apply(m, 1, function(r){r%*%cols_to_keep})
#>  [1] 1 1 2 2 0 3 2 2 1 3
```

As you can see, the first row was [1 0 1 1 0], of which we only want to keep for summation columns 2,3, and 5 which is the vector [. 0 1 . 0] and as a result the sum we are returned is 1.